# Why are iCloud-synced folders hidden in Finder; can they be unhidden w/o disabling sync?

Tags: icloud, finder

If I opt to sync folders (such as Documents and Desktop) with iCloud, they become hidden in Finder.

- I can still access them in Finder by keyboard shortcuts <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> (and by `Menubar / Go / Go to Folder…`).
- Their paths in Finder still show as being in my home directory (`/Users/~/Documents` and `/Users/~/Desktop`).
- Their locations in Terminal still show as being in my home directory.
- They seem to be hidden in the same way that my user Library folder is hidden (ie, not by mere dot-prefix).

Why are they hidden from Finder?

Can they be unhidden without disabling iCloud sync?

[image: home]

[image: desktop]

[image: hidden]

Comment: Please elaborate how they are hidden.   Are you saying that if you point Finder to your Home Folder, the directories aren't shown?  Can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: try Command + Shift + Period(.) to show them

Comment: I've added screenshots to elaborate.

Comment: I'm aware that command-shift-period can toggle all hidden folders, but that doesn't answer either question.